# Include more than one list of arguments with docopt

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, docopt

I am using the [docopt library](http://docopt.org).

I couldn't find out the way to accomplish the following requirement:

The docstring is:

```
"""
aTXT tool

Usage:
  aTXT <source>... [--ext <ext>...]

Options:
    --ext       message

"""
```

From the shell, I want to write something like this:

```
atxt a b c --ext e f g
```

The result dictionary from `docopt` output is the following:

```
 {'--ext': True,
 '<ext>': [],
 '<source>': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f']}
```

But, I need it to be the following:

```
 {'--ext': True,
 '<ext>': ['e', 'f', 'g'],
 '<source>': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not been able to find a way of passing a list directly into the Docopt argument dictionary. However, I have worked out a solution that has allowed me to pass a string into Docopt, then convert that string into a list.

There are issues with your Docopt `__doc__` and I revised them so that I could test the solution specific to your case. This code was written in Python 3.4 .

In command line:

```
python3 gitHubTest.py a,b,c -e 'e,f,g'
```

In `gitHubTest.py`:

```
"""
aTXT tool

Usage:
  aTXT.py [options] (<source>)

Options:
  -e ext, --extension=ext    message

"""
from docopt import docopt

def main(args) :
    if args['--extension'] != None:
        extensions = args['--extension'].rsplit(sep=',')
        print (extensions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__, version='1.00')
    print (args)
    main(args)
```

It returns:

```
{
'--extension': 'e,f,g',
'<source>': 'a,b,c'
}
['e', 'f', 'g']
```

The variable `extensions` created in `main()` is now the list you were hoping to pass in.

Comment: I wish there was a way to do it properly with docopt... As far as I understand, having multiple lists like OP wants is totally legitimate. And it's possible with argparse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763023/4671300