# How to pass an entire list as command line argument in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to pass two lists containing integers as arguments to a python code. But `sys.argv[i]` gets the parameters as a list of string.

Input would look like,

```
$ python filename.py [2,3,4,5] [1,2,3,4]
```

I found the following hack to convert the list.

```
strA = sys.argv[1].replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split()
strB = sys.argv[2].replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split()
A = [float(i) for i in strA]
B = [float (i) for i in strB]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can look into [serialization techniques](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html); this is what I usually do when I have to pass list-like structures as parameters via the command line. You could also look into JSON or other forms of data serialization. (But before you get too far into a solution, I'd make sure passing lists as parameters on the command line truly is what you need, and that this isn't an X-Y problem)

Comment: Why not `lists = [[int(el) for el in arg[1:-1].split(',')] for arg in sys.argv[1:]]`? Here you can see that the brackets are rather useless in this case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Command line arguments are always passed as strings. You will need to parse them into your required data type yourself.

```
>>> input = "[2,3,4,5]"
>>> map(float, input.strip('[]').split(','))
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>> A = map(float, input.strip('[]').split(','))
>>> print(A, type(A))
([2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], <type 'list'>)
```

There are libraries like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [click](http://click.pocoo.org) that let you define your own argument type conversion but `argparse` treats `"[2,3,4]"` the same as `[` `2` `,` `3` `,` `4` `]` so I doubt it will be useful.

*edit Jan 2019* This answer seems to get a bit of action still so I'll add another option taken directly from the argparse docs.

You can use `action=append` to allow repeated arguments to be collected into a single list.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --foo 2'.split())
Namespace(foo=['1', '2'])
```

In this case you would pass `--foo ?` once for each list item. Using OPs example: `python filename.py --foo 2 --foo 3 --foo 4 --foo 5` would result in `foo=[2,3,4,5]`

Comment: `print(A)` gives out a `<map object>`.

Comment: convert A to list like: A = list(map(int, input.strip('[]').split(',')))
print(A, type(A))

Comment: I originally wrote this in 2015 using python2 in which map is returning a list. Python 3 does indeed return a map (iterator)

Comment: So please add this Info to your original answer for prominent clarification.

Answer (score 140):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), be explicit and pass in actual lists of parameters

```
import argparse
# defined command line options
# this also generates --help and error handling
CLI=argparse.ArgumentParser()
CLI.add_argument(
  "--lista",  # name on the CLI - drop the `--` for positional/required parameters
  nargs="*",  # 0 or more values expected => creates a list
  type=int,
  default=[1, 2, 3],  # default if nothing is provided
)
CLI.add_argument(
  "--listb",
  nargs="*",
  type=float,  # any type/callable can be used here
  default=[],
)

# parse the command line
args = CLI.parse_args()
# access CLI options
print("lista: %r" % args.lista)
print("listb: %r" % args.listb)
```

You can then call it using

```
$ python my_app.py --listb 5 6 7 8 --lista  1 2 3 4
lista: [1, 2, 3, 4]
listb: [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Comment: This is the best answer out there. Just use nargs of argparse.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi wax on wax off

Comment: This one is the better coding practice. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

I tested this on my end, and my input looks like this:

```
python foo.py "[1,2,3,4]" "[5,6,7,8,9]"
```

I'm doing the following to convert the two params of interest:

```
import ast
import sys

list1 = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
list2 = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: throws `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000024929290518>`, my argument is `"[n01530575,n01530576]"`

Answer (score 16):

Why not:

```
python foo.py 1,2,3,4 5,6,7,8
```

Much cleaner than trying to eval python and doesn't require your user to know python format.

```
import sys

list1 = sys.argv[1].split(',')
list2 = [int(c) for c in sys.argv[2].split(',')]  # if you want ints
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also do the following:

say, you have `foo.py` :

```
import json
import sys
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print data, type(data)
```

Then if you run the above as : `python foo.py "[1,2,3]"`

Output:

`[1, 2, 3] <type 'list'>`

Comment: it thorws `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: p.s. my argument is `"[n01530575,n01530576]"`

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use [`nargs='+'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) option of argparse

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--myarg', dest='myarg', required=False, help='--myarg 100 100 100 takes a list of 3 elements, each is of value 100 ', nargs='+', type=int, default=[100,100,100])
```

You can then pass arguments like this:

```
python your_file.py --myarg 1 2 3
```

This will be stored in your program in myarg as [1,2,3]

```
print(myarg)
```

Outputs:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way pass a list in a command line argument. Command line arguments are always string. But there is a better way to convert it to list. You can do it like that:

```
import ast

A = ast.literal_eval(strA)
B = ast.literal_eval(strB)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape:

```
python some.py \[2,3,4,5\] \[1,2,3,4\]
```

some.py

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[2]
```

this gives me:

```
[2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4]
```

[image: Bash out]

**UPDATE**:

```
import sys
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
b = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[2])

for a in d:
    print a

for e in b:
    print e
```

first will give:

```
2
3
4
5
```

and second will give

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: what happens when you print the type of what you did there?

Comment: That still gives a string when you output the type

Comment: i have updated answer. but i see now it is same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/32762516/1108279

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this way:

Suppose you are trying to pass a list of numbers to Python code:

```
python3 check.py --ids 25,36
```

Inside the code, you just need to read ids as follows:

```
list(eval(args.ids))
```

Then you will see:

[25,36]