# Pass a list to a Python script as a command line argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am currently facing a problem while I want to put list as argument.
list is this format :

```
[1,0,0,0]
```

and I'm going to do something like this in another python code:

```
os.system('python main.py %s' %([list]))
```

When I printed sys.argv[1] in main.py, it was not what I wanted : It print

> [1,

How can I use this list in `main.py` ?

Comment: I guess you should check the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761999/how-to-pass-an-entire-list-as-command-line-argument-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an entire list as command line argument in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761999/how-to-pass-an-entire-list-as-command-line-argument-in-python)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I dont think its duplicate

Comment: @sambasivarao not helpful without explaining why. My reasoning is: The OP is seeking to pass a non-string as an argument. That question addresses how to do this.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The problem is when trying to pass the list from another python file and trying to it print sys.argv[1] it is printing only the partial list, so it is taking each argument separated by a comma.

Comment: @Sang-ilPark check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is when you are passing the list as the command line argument without quotes around it, the python is reading each comma separated value as a single argument. Just wrap the quotes around the string as shown below

main.py file:

```
import sys
import ast
print sys.argv[1]
print type(ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1]))
```

passing the non string as the argument:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("python main.py '%s'"%[1,2])
[1, 2]
<type 'list'>
0
```

Passing a list or dict as a variable:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> os.system("python main.py '%s'"%a)
[1, 2]
<type 'list'>
0
>>> dic = {1:2,2:3}
>>> os.system("python main.py '%s'"%dic)
{1: 2, 2: 3}
<type 'dict'>
0
```

**EDIT**:

Alternate solution: using string format

```
>>>a = [1,2]
>>> os.system("python main.py '{}'".format(a))
[1, 2]
<type 'list'>
0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thank you for the catch, I don't clearly know what the problem is, but try using the format(). For more see my edit above