# How to pass an entire list as command line argument in Python when the list comes from a json file

Tags: python, json, command-line-arguments, jq

Based on one of the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761999/how-to-pass-an-entire-list-as-command-line-argument-in-python/32763023), one can successfully pass a list using `nargs`.

However, I am not sure how to pass correctly a list when the list is actually retrieved from a json file. All the attempts made returns always a list of one and I was wondering how can one successfully do that from the command line (i.e. no use of json parsing inside the python script).

Main attempt using a toy example (very similar to the one of the post mentioned above).

**app_parsing_lists.py**

```py
import argparse
# defined command line options
# this also generates --help and error handling
CLI=argparse.ArgumentParser()
CLI.add_argument(
  "--lista",  # name on the CLI - drop the `--` for positional/required parameters
  nargs="*",  # 0 or more values expected => creates a list
  type=str,
  default=["1", "2", "3"],  # default if nothing is provided
)

# parse the command line
args = CLI.parse_args()
# access CLI options
print("lista: %r" % args.lista)
```

**file.json**

```json
{"field": [6, 7, 8]}
```

From CLI:

```sh
inlist=$(jq -r '.field | join(" ")' file.json)
python app_parsing_lists.py --lista $inlist
```

It prints `lista: ['6 7 8']`

But the behavior wanted is `lista: ['6', '7', '8']`

How can one achieve that?

Comment: You are using .join() which returns a string with seperation of the argument passed, 
Try split()

Comment: has you try `%s` instead of `%r`. you may also print `args` to see how it take your args. Che thech `inlist` to see if it has `"`in it. and double check with `--inlist 6 7 8` behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: don't join.

More specifically:

```
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista $(echo '{"field": [6, 7, 8]}' | jq -r .field[])
lista: ['6', '7', '8']
```

In long: consider these examples, all using `%r` --

```
$ inlist=("4" "5" "6")
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista ${inlist[@]}
lista: ['4', '5', '6']
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista "${inlist[@]}"
lista: ['4', '5', '6']
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista $(jq -n '5,6,7')
lista: ['5', '6', '7']
$ inlist=($(jq -n '5,6,7'))
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista $inlist
lista: ['5']
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista "$inlist"
lista: ['5']
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista ${inlist[@]}
lista: ['5', '6', '7']
$
```

#### Caveat

If any of the list items contains a space, a different approach will be needed, as illustrated by:

```
$ lista=("a b" 2 3)

$ for i in "${lista[@]}" ; do echo $i ; done
a b
2
3

$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista "${lista[@]}"
lista: ['a b', '2', '3']

$ lista=($(echo '{"field": ["a b", 7, 8]}' | jq .field[]))
$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista "${lista[@]}"
lista: ['"a', 'b"', '7', '8']
```

Solution

```
unset lista
while IFS= read -r line ; do lista+=($line)
done < <(printf "%s\n" '{"field": ["a b", 7, 8]}' | jq -r .field[])

$ python app_parsing_lists.py --lista ${lista[@]}
lista: ['a b', '7', '8']
$
```

Comment: How can I get `inlist=("4" "5" "6")` with `jq`? If I remove the join and run `inlist=$(jq -r '.field' file.json)` it still doesn't work.

Comment: for the items with spaces how can one make it work in bash? I made it work successfully with zsh but with bash it stills split on the space within the value.