# Is it possible to pass an entire list as a command line argument in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass a list of elements as an argument to an R script.

`R -f myscript.R --people "James" "John" "Emily" "Anna"`

I'm trying to make use of the [optparse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optparse/) library to try and do the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761999/how-to-pass-an-entire-list-as-command-line-argument-in-python) which uses the argparser in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `optparse` accepts only one argument for each "flag". I would use a comma-separated list:

```
R -f myscript.R --people James,John,Emily,Anna
```

And in your script you get the character string `"James,John,Emily,Anna"` that you can split with `strsplit` to get the vector of names.